# Argument List Too Long - Curl - GeoJSON

Tags: bash, curl, geojson

I am trying to feed a GeoJSON to this [data service](https://github.com/UW-Macrostrat/gplates-reconstruct#gplates-reconstruction-service) using the following bash code.

```
curl -X POST -F "shape=$(cat myfile.geojson)" \
-F 'age=69' -o reconstructed_myfile.geojson \
https://dev.macrostrat.org/reconstruct
```

However, I am getting an "Argument list too long" error. I see a lot of questions open on stack related to this issue, but I do not understand how to convert the answers given in those threads to this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `<filename` or `@filename`:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F 'shape=<myfile.geojson' \
     -F 'age=69' \
     -o 'reconstructed_myfile.geojson' \
     -- 'https://dev.macrostrat.org/reconstruct'
```

See `man curl` for details:

```
$ man curl | awk '$1 ~ /-F/' RS=
   -F, --form <name=content>
          (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has
          pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data  using  the
          Content-Type  multi‐ part/form-data  according  to RFC 2388. This
          enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to
          be a file, prefix the file name with an  @ sign.  To just get the
          content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The
          difference between @ and < is then  that  @  makes  a  file  get
          attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field
          and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
```

Comment: Wouldn't `<` be more appropriate than `@` here?

Comment: Yes, `<` makes more sense for me. Unfortunately, I get a 500 internal service error back as my GeoJSON. This might suggest a problem on the data service side rather than the Curl bit, but the data service does work using the original syntax with smaller files.